# How often are new iPod touch versions released?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I am wondering whether Apple releases a new iPod touch version once or twice a year (like the iPhone S which comes after a few months from the original release).

Thanks.

Comment: Guessing is discouraged as it's no better than a poll. The wikipedia entries on past models seems to be the best place to see what has happened and be prepared for reading the tea leaves for guessing what and when Apple will release new product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice resource for questions like this is the [Macrumors Buyer's Guide](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com), which lists average time between product updates and a recommendation of whether to buy or wait. As the iPod touch is concerned, this product is listed with a last release date of Oct 9, 2012, and an average update cycle of every 342 days (approximately one year).